# How to use "eingehen"?

Tags: word-usage

I know that *eingehen* means to arrive:

> 1. All die Computer sind in Costco ***eingegangen.***

This Verb has a lot of meanings and they are:

a: To take a chance.

> Er ***geht*** ein Risiko ***ein***, in der Lotterie zu gewinnen.

b: to die out

> Ohne Wasser werden die Tomatenpflanzen ***eingehen.***

c: to comprehend

> Mir ***geht*** die Regeln des Spieles ***ein.***

Can I use *eingehen* with people?

> Ich gehe in eine Firma ein.

Comment: "Ich gehe in eine Firma ein" is funny, but do make sure not to use the dative there, "ich gehe in einer Firma ein", which is funnier still. (Funny, of course, does not mean ungrammatical.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed "eingehen" has a lot of meanings, but actually "arrive" is not one of them. For arrive you would rather use words like "ankommen" or "eintreffen". 
And for the sentence you ask about and for people in general you would use "eintreten".
"Ich trete in eine Firma ein."

Comment: All die Rechner sind in Costco eingetroffen. (?)

Comment: Ok. To this first sentence I need to say that the grammar could be considered as right. But if you use "eingegangen" it is more from an accouting point of view, like entered the journal. So "eingetroffen" is definitly the way to go. Normally you would say "Alle Rechner..." or "Die Rechner..." (if you talked about them before and you have a clear reference). a) and b) are fine. c) I am not sure what you want to say, but I think it should be "Ich verstehe die Regeln des Spiels".

Comment: But eingehen has also the meaning of ' to comprehend'.

Comment: For sure you could find some context, where you would translate eingehen with comprehend, but not in this example. I think the other very important meaning for "eingehen" that you search here is something like "auf jemanden/auf etwas eingehen", which is like to "be responsive to somebody/something" or also "go in detail into something". I could also say: "Ich bin in dieser Situation wirklich sehr auf sie eingegangen.", which would mean that I really listened to her and cared for her emotions in this situation.

Comment: *Eingehen* sounds technical (like in *Wareneingang*) in the first sentence, but that may be what is wanted. However, it would be „Alle Computer sind *bei* Costco eingegangen“. If Costco was a country, then you would say „... sind in Costco eingetroffen“.

Answer (score 1):

The most important use was missing and that is the one that works with people:

> Ich gehe auf dich ein.

It also works with things.

> Ich gehe auf die Frage ein.

It is hard to translate that into one English word but the opposite would be *to ignore* or *to brush off all the person says*.

> I listen to what you say/ I do care what you want.
>
> I say something about/answer the question.